# How should I downgrade just the tomcat server my springboot application runs on without changing spring-boot-starter-parent version

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a server that can only run tomcat 8.0.32 and I developed my application on tomcat 9.0.50. There anyway I can just change the tomcat in my pom.xml so that my application runs the same just on tomcat 8.0.32.

Comment: Try to improve your question as described in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you deploy a Spring Boot application on an external Tomcat its version **does not** have to match that of the embedded Tomcat. There are however restrictions due to the Servlet API version required by Spring. BTW: Tomcat 8.0 reached end-of-life many years ago, only Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0 are still supported (Tomcat 10 is not compatible with Spring).

Comment: I see, thank you for your response! I'm getting errors while trying to deploy my application on tomcat 8 due to unsupported methods. Do you have any suggestions on how to overcome this?